# Disable GCC narrowing conversion errors

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I have code from over 20 years in C/C++ and one technique used to handle variable data sizes was to let automatic type conversion handle it.

For example:

`#define MY_STATUS_UNDEFINED (-1)`

Then if it was compared/used against a `int64_t` it was auto expanded to `-1LL`, for `uint64_t` to `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`, for `uint32_t` to `0xFFFFFFFF`, `int16_t` to `-1`, `uint16_t` to `0xFFFF`, etc..

However, now I'm getting errors with the newer gcc versions that complain about narrowing conversion. In this case it was a `switch` statement with a `UINT` variable.

```
switch (myuint) {
  case MY_STATUS_UNDEFINED: 
    break;
}
```

What is the recommended way to get it to not error out?

What is the easiest way to get it to not error out?

What is the cleanest way so it doesn't error out and doesn't give any warning message?

Essentially, I want it to do the auto type conversion properly but no warning or errors.

Comment: Are you looking to shut off specific warnings globally, or perhaps isolate specific sections of code where they're suppressed, but enabled everywhere else?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I added: Essentially, I want it to do the auto type conversion properly but no warning or errors.  I could turn it off globally in this project.

Comment: Going through every warning of this sort in a huge code base and make sure it does the right thing can take a day - and then you are not worried later. Worth it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following brief example:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

#define MY_STATUS_UNDEFINED (-1)

void bar()
{
    std::cout << "It works\n";
}

void foo(uint32_t n)
{
    switch (n) {
    case MY_STATUS_UNDEFINED:
        bar();
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    foo(0xFFFFFFFF);
    return 0;
}
```

You are seeing the following error from gcc:

```
error: narrowing conversion of ‘-1’ from ‘int’ to ‘unsigned int’ [-Wnarrowing]
```

Now, pay careful attention to the error message. gcc is telling the exact option to shut this off. See the `[-Wnarrowing]` annotation? That's the compilation flag that's responsible for ***producing*** this error message.

To turn it off, stick a "no-" in front of it:

```
-Wno-narrowing
```

All gcc diagnostics use this convention. Now the shown code will compile, run, and produce the expected result:

```
It works!
```

Add `-Wno-narrowing` to your global compilation options.

You should really consider this to be only a temporary band-aid solution. These compilation errors are exactly what you want. They're telling you about real or potential problems. `-Wall -Werror -Wsuggest-override -Wreturn-type` are my favorite compilation options.

Comment: I went with -Wno-narrowing - I'd like to leave it enabled to the point where when narrowing would work fine there is no warning but if it actually was something that was a potential problem because the compiler didn't really know what to do, then give the error/warning.  That be perfect.

Comment: Well, `-Wno-narrowing` is an all-or-nothing proposition; but I'm curious how "potential problem" can be logically defined here. Why is this specific conversion here is not a "potential problem"? How would the compiler figure out: yes -1 would be ok to mutate to its 2s-complement value, but -2 not, for example?

Comment: the old trusted automatic type conversion rules would apply because they worked well.  I don't recall the details off the top of my head, but I recall potential problems with char vs unsigned char having potential issues.

Comment: @user3161924 On a C system where `int/unsigned` was 64-bit, this `foo()` code would not work as you hope.  32-bit unsigned  `n` would never equate to  -1.  IMO, comparing an unsigned with a negative value is simple setting up for a future bug.  True that 64-bit `int` is very uncommon - today, yet your general approach for mixing sign-ness operands is one step closer to the precipice.  Warnings are there to highlight this issue.  Good luck.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Actually, -Wno-narrowing doesn't have to be an all-or-nothing proposition, since you could instrument individual source files (or header files, which sometimes is preferable) with `_Pragma("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Wnarrowing\"")` to disable this error from that point on in the translation unit. Or utilize `_Pragma("GCC diagnostic push")` and `_Pragma("GCC diagnostic pop")` along with to limit the scope further.